# Some jQuery syntax issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to use this jQuery `click()` function and for some arcane reasons it keeps on failing on some apparent syntactical error.  I am not sure why.  Below is my code snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.Trial').click(function () {
      alert("User clicked on Trial Object");
   });
});
```

I am not sure what is wrong with it.

Comment: `some apparant syntactical error` you are saying? Hmm, let me look for my magic crystal ball. Will get back to you as soon as I find it and it tells me the exact error message you are getting. While waiting for answer you could then apply `the apparent syntactical fix` to solve your problem.

Comment: what's the html you're trying to interface with?

Comment: what's the actual error message.  what scripts do you have around this?  what browser?

Comment: What does "keeps failing" mean?  Are you getting an error or just not getting the alert?

Comment: This code is fine, the error is elsewhere.  What is the exact error you're getting?

Comment: First things first: make sure you've included the jQuery library at the top of your page.

Comment: It just says "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected" and does not give any further explanation. It is IE9. It is basically not Pure HTMl that I am trying to interface with.

Comment: Aren't you misspelling the class name?

Comment: @Californicated, lesson number 1: don't use IE to develop web applications. Use some real web browser. You can use IE occasionally for surfing and stuff like this but once you get into writing software stay away from it. For example FireFox and Google Chrome are pretty nice. They will tell you the exact error message instead of spitting some meaningless crap which is what IE does and which is what IE **is**. I will be the happiest man on Earth when Microsoft announces the death of IE or when Microsoft make it as good as other browsers.

Comment: @Californicated: Is the only JavaScript code (script tag) on your page?  The error may be in a another script tag/JavaScript file.

Comment: @Darin - Come on man, everyone knows you use the boiling cauldron to debug js errors... meanwhile, californicated - try replacing $ with jQuery. Maybe a conflict in older versions. Otherwise I would say you have an error in js anywhere before this line of code. If this code above is within a script tag with anything else, look there first. Else, you'll have to paste the rest of the js on the page or we really would need a boiling cauldron to help you.

Comment: It just says "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected" and does not give any further explanation. It is IE9. It is basically not Pure HTMl that I am trying to interface with. Because I am producing HTMl from XSLT. and that XSLT is something like this "<img name ="IMG@name" src ="C:\temp\Test.jpg" class = "Trial"/>"

Comment: @californicated it doesn't matter where you're getting your html, jsut that you're getting it. What we need isn't what's in your code, it's what's on the page. If you can't provide a link, and don't know how to inspect the source then there really isn't much we can do to guess where you've gone wrong. Because as has been pointed out, that jquery is fine.

Comment: @Californicated: Without more of your code, there's not much we can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted worked fine: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/xDGgh/

Check your error log for a specific error or line number. Try to comment-out different blocks of code to find the error (if you comment-out the code with the error, the rest of your JS will work). Developing with a browser that has good developer tools is extremely helpful; [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) is a great add-on for Firefox.